# React.js not working on Plunker

Tags: reactjs, plunker

I'm setting up a very simple React.js Plunker which does not seem to be working. My expectation is that the button should display. Can anyone help out and let me know what is wrong?

http://plnkr.co/edit/dGn5tJx4UbD1yXX0Q3vW?p=preview

```
var Button = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return: (
        <button>Test</button>
      )
  }
});

React.render(<Button />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has a colon after the return statement, which is causing it to throw a syntax error:

```
return:
```

Here's an updated/fixed [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/58xiSRxN0CXknYCbbtoQ?p=preview).